# get simple value from string array in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

My code is like...

```
NSString *str=[arrInitiatives valueForKey:@"FileName"];
NSLog(@"file name ----> %@",str);

 NSString *imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", PUBLIC_UTILITY_FORMS_URL,str];
 NSLog(@"----> %@",imageUrl);
[_image_imageview setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"noimage.png"]];
//http://setupolice.org/brcsetu/UploadFile/Lighthouse4908.jpg
```

from this code,i will get this

```
file name ----> (
    "Lighthouse4908.jpg"
)

 ----> http://setupolice.org/brcsetu/UploadFile/(
    "Lighthouse4908.jpg"
)

I want this   

----> http://setupolice.org/brcsetu/UploadFile/Lighthouse4908.jpg
```

Comment: check NSString class docs, they have method to tell path extension and file name etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *str=[[arrInitiatives valueForKey:@"FileName"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Regards,

Amit

Answer (score 0):

When you create the *str* variable with code

```
NSString *str=[arrInitiatives valueForKey:@"FileName"];
```

In fact it doesn't return *NSString* object but *NSArray* object. That's why filename is inside parenthesis in log:

```
file name ----> (
"Lighthouse4908.jpg"
)
```

If you're sure that filename will always be present in the array you can try what @Amit Kalghatgi suggested in his answer.

The problem is that when this array is empty you will get an error during execution of this code. I would rather do something like this:

```
NSArray *filenames = [arrInitiatives valueForKey:@"FileName"];
NSString *str = nil;
if (filenames.count) {
    str =[arrInitiatives valueForKey:@"FileName"];
}
NSLog(@"file name ----> %@",str);
```

Of course before creating *imageUrl* you'll have to check if *str* is nil or not.